# iOS 7: UITextView UITextInputTraits bug?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextinputtraits

Today while working on [Reveal](http://revealapp.com) I became aware of a bug in iOS 7's [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html)'s 
handling of the [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits) protocol.

The `UITextInputTraits` protocol has methods for setting what sort of keyboard
should be shown when a user taps on a `UITextView` and other such things.

iOS 7 also introduced a new `selectable` property on `UITextView` for controlling whether
text selection is enabled.  This is much better than the methods required in previous 
releases of iOS, where you had to subclass UITextView and return no for 
`canBecomeFirstResponder` or alternatively set an `inputDelegate` and
handle the appropriate delegate callbacks to stop selection for occurring.

Unfortunately, setting both `editable` and `selectable` to NO in iOS 7 breaks all of the
`UITextInputTraits` methods.  If you attempt to call any of them your app will crash 
with an `instance does not respond to selector` exception.  Which is weird because the 
`UITextView` instance will return YES if you call `respondsToSelector:` for any of the
methods declared in the `UITextInputTraits` protocol.

This appears to me to be a bug in iOS 7.  I've reported it to Apple as radar://15063164.

I've also noticed that for UITextView's created via code (rather than in Storyboards) this bug 
doesn't express. I'm not sure why yet. There may be additional properties at work or 
the fact that the UITextView is initialised via `initWithCoder:` rather than 
`initWithFrame:` and may be in a different state due to this.

Some code that shows the bug:

```
@interface IBAViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *editableAndSelectable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *selectable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *notEditableOrSelectable;

@end

@implementation IBAViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* 
     Remove the define below and we won't crash on the last NSAssert below.  Leave it in
     and we crash (assuming we've created and connected three UITextView's to the IBOutlets above
     in a storyboard for this view controller).
    */

#define USING_STORYBOARD

#ifndef USING_STORYBOARD
    self.editableAndSelectable = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.selectable = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.notEditableOrSelectable = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    [self.view addSubview:self.editableAndSelectable];
    [self.view addSubview:self.selectable];
    [self.view addSubview:self.notEditableOrSelectable];
#endif

    self.editableAndSelectable.text = @"Text1";
    self.editableAndSelectable.editable = YES;
    self.editableAndSelectable.selectable = YES;

    self.selectable.text = @"Text2";
    self.selectable.editable = NO;
    self.selectable.selectable = YES;

    self.notEditableOrSelectable.text = @"Text3";
    self.notEditableOrSelectable.editable = NO;
    self.notEditableOrSelectable.selectable = NO;

    NSAssert(self.editableAndSelectable.editable == YES, @"Huh?");
    NSAssert(self.editableAndSelectable.selectable == YES, @"Huh?");

    NSAssert([self.editableAndSelectable respondsToSelector:@selector(isSecureTextEntry)], @"Huh?");
    NSAssert([self.editableAndSelectable isSecureTextEntry] == NO, @"Huh?");

    NSAssert(self.selectable.editable == NO, @"Huh?");
    NSAssert(self.selectable.selectable == YES, @"Huh?");

    NSAssert([self.editableAndSelectable respondsToSelector:@selector(isSecureTextEntry)], @"Huh?");
    NSAssert([self.editableAndSelectable isSecureTextEntry] == NO, @"Huh?");

    NSAssert(self.notEditableOrSelectable.editable == NO, @"Huh?");
    NSAssert(self.notEditableOrSelectable.selectable == NO, @"Huh?");

    NSAssert([self.notEditableOrSelectable respondsToSelector:@selector(isSecureTextEntry)], @"Huh?");
    NSAssert([self.notEditableOrSelectable isSecureTextEntry] == NO, @"Huh?"); // crashes here (on iOS 7)
}

@end
```

Has anyone else seen this? Or have any ideas?

Comment: I have a related [issue here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250633/uitextview-not-responding-to-uitextinputtraits-in-ios7?lq=1)  I see you implemented a work-around for Reveal.  Do you have any insights to share?